# Classes not found when archiving SwiftUI app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, archive

I have been working on a 100% SwiftUI app and am fairly into the project.
The project compiles and builds without issues when running on both simulator and device.
However if I try to compile the project I get a bunch of errors stating certain classes cannot be found across the project.

2 of these are CoreData auto generated classes.
1 is a global struct called Globals.swift

[image]

Has anyone else encountered this issue with Xcode 12.4?

Comment: re create the project again from Zero with copy and past codes

Comment: I've filed a bug report with Apple, I might give this is a shot in the meantime.

Comment: creating a new project was easier than make a ticket I think

Answer (score 0):

You have probably changed some architecture settings

Try

- Click target next to stop button
- Select Edit Scheme
- Select Run on the left
- Select Info (top center)
- Change Build Configuration from Debug to Release
- Then build your project as you have been on a Device

If you get the same error you know something is going on between DEBUG and RELEASE builds.

Make a new project and compare the "Build Settings" of your current target and the "Build Settings" of you new empty project.

Pay attention to the ones that have DEBUG and RELEASE options such as
Architectures > Build Active Architectures Only

And anything else you might have changed because of a pod or other dependency.

Comment: This is a really good idea. Unfortunately when changing the build configuration to release I am able to run the app in the simulator without issues.

Comment: Simulator wouldn't have the issue the issue is for arm64 that is why I said try it on a device. Simulator runs on x86_64. I think that you are excluding arm64 somehow.

Comment: I just built and run the app with a release build setting on device.